# Triggering a method of an object that will soon be replaced

Tags: javascript, function, object, hash, settimeout

Given this var:

```
somevar = {dothis: function(){console('yay')}};
```

If I want to hijack it, I would think i'd do something like:

```
tempvar = somevar;
somevar = function(){ console.log('yoink'); tempvar();};
```

But if I know that the var is going to be redefined in 60 seconds, and I want to hijack it in 65 seconds, how do I do that? Wouldn't a setTimeout parse the function immediately, and then refer to the old hijacked function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// initial data
var somevar = {
  dothis: function(){
    console.log('yay');
  }
};

somevar.dothis(); // output: yay

// hijacking in 1 second
setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('hijacking');
    somevar.dothis = (function (orig) {
        return function () {
            console.log('yoink');
            orig.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    }(somevar.dothis));
}, 1000);

// saved reference running 1.5 seconds later (0.5 seconds after hijacking)
setTimeout(somevar.dothis, 1500); // output (still): yay

// live reference running 2 seconds later (1 second after hijacking)
setTimeout(function () {
  somevar.dothis(); // output: yoink / yay
}, 2000);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MDLZt/

Comment: Thanks - would you mind explaining or posting a link describing the logic behind this technique. I broadly understand (or think) that it's a matter of referencing the function vs invoking it, but I'd love to have a deeper grasp of it.

Comment: @Matrym I'm not sure which part of the code you mean. Is it the hijacking or the timed invoking? About the latter I can only say (because I myself don't really know it) that it seems that `setTimeout` will save the reference at the time of invoking `setTimeout`. Whereas the 2nd version will search for  `somevar.dothis` in the accessible scope chain and thus will find the hijacked one.